# Adjusting formulas to fit within side VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running into a bit of issues getting my formula to work within VBA.

VBA:

```
Range("K2").Formula = "=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(J2,{"*Advanced Diploma*","*Diploma*"})),H2/10,H2/10*2)"
```

Excel:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(J2,{"*Advanced Diploma*","*Diploma*"})),H2/10,H2/10*2)
```

The error I am getting is that there is a syntax error.
Please disregard discrepancy between cells referenced.

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double up like this `""` in order to escape `"`:

```
Range("K2").Formula = "=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(J2,{""*Advanced Diploma*"",""*Diploma*""})),H2/10,H2/10*2)"
```